# Python Scipy Optimizer: Constraints are not working as expected

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm doing stock portfolio volatility minimization with two constraints:

1. Sum of stock weights must be = 1, this works fine.
2. Sum of squared weights must be less than 0.02, this is done in order to have at least 50 stocks in the portfolio.There are enough stocks in the composition (around 100), so there should not be any issues to meet this constraint.

However, the second constraint is not working for some reason. Can somebody please explain me how to set up these bounds correctly?

```python
import scipy.optimize as spo

def portfolio_vol(w):

    #compute porfolio volatility
    portfolio_volatility = np.sqrt(w.T.dot(cov_matrix).dot(w))
    return portfolio_volatility


def find_optimal_allocations():
    bnds = tuple((0.00, 0.02) for x in weights)
    cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - sum(x)}, {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x**2) - 0.02})
    result = spo.minimize(portfolio_vol, weights, method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)
    return result.x
```

Comment: your inequality constraint is not defined correctly. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html - You have to provide the `g_i(x)`, not a boolean value.

Comment: Can you please advise how to do that? I can't find any examples where the constraint is in the form of ">" or "<"

Comment: Thought that I have figured it out by changing second constraint to this  `sum(x**2) - 0.02` but it still does not work properly, @cel can you suggest how to correct it?

Comment: Where do your `weights` come from? Do the initial weights fullfill the inequality constraint?

Comment: Also `g_i(x) >= 0`, therefore `sum(x**2) >= 0.02`, but you said, you want to have a `<=` here.

Comment: ah ok, solved it, it should be like this `-sum(x**2) + 0.02`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to scipy, you can use `cvxpy`.
This code should work for you. (I assumed the weights are non-negative. Otherwise, just remove `x >= 0` from the constraints.)

```
import cvxpy as cvx
import numpy as np

n = 100
M = np.random.random((n,n))
cov_matrix = np.cov(M)

x = cvx.Variable(n)
constraints = [x >= 0, cvx.sum_entries(x) == 1, cvx.sum_squares(x) <= 0.02]

objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.quad_form(x,cov_matrix))
prob = cvx.Problem(objective,constraints)
prob.solve()

print(prob.value)
print(prob.variables()[0].value
```

Comment: I assume this works and is a good solution, but the question was specifically asking about SciPy and why a constraint might be ignored. This does not answer that.